# Error en terminal en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

[image: Terminal de android studio 2.2.1] Al querer obtener la SHA-1. de mapas la terminal parecer embasurarse sin yo teclear ningún código y no se si es porque tengo windows 7 y el android studio es la version 2.2.1

Comment: ¿Embarazarse? Yo sugiero no utilizar modismos coloquiales para que todos podamos entender ya que existimos usuarios de diferentes países. 

Comment: Aquí podrías encontrar una solución: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es obtener la SHA1 usa la consola de comandos y haz lo siguiente

***C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin>***

y después escribe en la consola y da enter.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "c:\users\tu_nombre_de_usuario\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

cuando presiones enter te deberá de aparecer la sha1